# Replacement For An Old Over the Range Microwave GE Spacemaker Model # JVM1341WW 002

Tags: microwave-oven

My 1997 over the range G.E. Spacemaker microwave broke. The model number is JVM1341WW 002.

Would anyone know if the measurements have to be exactly the same as the old one, or is it ok if the depth is about an inch more?

Comment: Any microwave that fits the opening and that you like would be a good replacement. You don't have to replace it with a GE Spacemaker. You may need to reformat your question about a specific problem rather than a shopping question which is off topic and will get closed.

Comment: Height and width are easy. For depth, you'll have to pull out the old one and measure how much space you have. But a big piece a lot of people don't think about is *exhaust fan ductwork* - it can go out the top or the back, rectangle or round, and different models may have different alignments, some adjustable, some not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measurements for depth don't have to be exactly the same. You can see the depth requirements in the installation manual for whatever new microwave hood you are considering, and compare the depth requirements with the space your old microwave hood took up. Most appliance companies and major appliance stores have PDF installation manuals posted on the website page for the model of microwave hood you're considering.

Here is an example of an installation diagram you'd be looking for in an [installation manual PDF](https://products-salsify.geappliances.com/image/upload/s--lEM3537p--/i0b9mdwmmx7xh6ldrjxs.pdf?_ga=2.128587145.441303812.1700399164-482018150.1700399164), which came from a microwave hood from [geappliances.com](https://products-salsify.geappliances.com/image/upload/s--lEM3537p--/i0b9mdwmmx7xh6ldrjxs.pdf?_ga=2.128587145.441303812.1700399164-482018150.1700399164). (Please note I'm not endorsing this hood model, it's just an example; links are for attribution.) The depth measurement is arrowed:
[image: microwave hood install diagram with depth highlighted]

Very often, upper kitchen cabinets have fairly standard depths (usually 12-13 inches or 300-330mm), unless your kitchen is super fancy from a custom cabinet shop. Most of the time, microwave hoods are fairly interchangeable regarding space needed, since the designers plan for standard-depth upper kitchen cabinetry.

As @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact pointed out in a comment on your question, you may also have to consider the ducting for the vent hood, if your existing setup has the vent hood directed to the outside. Some microwave hood installations don't have outside venting. You'll have to look at what's there and compare the hoped-for model's installation instructions.

If you are unsure whether a particular model microwave hood would fit, I believe it would be a good subject for a new question later if you posted a picture or three of the existing space for the microwave hood with the old microwave taken down, measurements of opening size (and duct size & location if there is a duct) and a model number and web link to the installation manual PDF. The gurus here can take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your super helpful explanation! It looks like the best thing to do is to take down the old microwave before I buy a new one. I know the duct is on top and vents outside. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your nuke is the standard 30" width for an Over The Range nuke.  Are you actually using yours OTR, or just over counter?

It appears to have the typical squirrel fan in the upper rear that can be rotated to vent upward or backward, so most any nuke you might buy should work with existing venting (if any).

As mentioned, the depth is what it is, and having the nuke stick out from the face of the cabinets isn't the end of the world (if it is for you, you'll need to find a less deep nuke).  Height can also vary, but most new nukes should fit.